# localStorage working on Localhost but not on server. What may cause this?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes an id as argument. Then I store that id on localStorage.

```
function setElementId(id){
  localStorage.setItem('elementId',id);
}
```

And in another page retrieve that id to display some respective content.

```
function displayElement(){
  var eid = localStorage.getItem('elementId');
  document.getElementById(eid).style.display = "block";
}
```

This works perfectly fine in localhost but doesn't work in server. In server, when another page loads, localStorage.getItem('elementId') returns null.

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('elementId'));
```

This gives null value. What is happening? Can anybody bestow upon me some of your great javascript knowledge? I would be thankful.

Comment: Have you checked the localstorage on the dev console, maybe you stored null into this elementId

Comment: Yep ! did that. As I said below, console.log( localStorage.getItem('elementId')) prints actual id on the same page where I did setItem()  but gives 'null' value on another page.

Comment: And on the dev console can you see the key elementId with null value or there is no  key either?

Comment: there is key elementId, and the value associated is null.

Comment: in this case your app set its value to null somehow

Comment: having this issue too.  frustrating

Answer (score 0):

The `localStorage` is shared per domain. If you store something on `localhost:8080`, you won't be able to access it on `example.com`.

Comment: I redid the whole thing on server. I mean i did store using localStorage.setItem() thing on the server as well, ain't that supposed to work for the domain ?

Comment: And I further found out that it works in the same page i.e. doing  console.log(localStorage.getItem('elementId'));  on the same page as setItem() works but returns null on another page .

Comment: What do you mean "on the server"? `localStorage` is a browser only API.

Comment: I uploaded the whole thing into my site's cpanel. And even rewrote the javascript part again and even changed the variable name for elementId.